# IIS - Different processing of default document in Integrated Pipeline mode?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, httpmodule

I have an HTTP Module to handle authentication from Facebook, which works fine in classic pipeline mode.

In integrated pipeline mode, however, I'm seeing an additional request pass through for the default document, which is causing the module to fail.  We look at the request (from Facebook) to retrieve and validate the user accessing our app.  The initial request authenticates fine, but then I see a *second* request, which lacks the posted form variables, and thus causes authentication to fail.

In integrated pipeline mode, an http request for "/" yields 2 AuthenticateRequests in a row:

1. A request where AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath = "~/"
2. A request where AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath = "~/default.aspx"

That second request loses all of the form values, so it fails to authenticate.  In classic mode, that second request is the only one that happens, and it preserves the form values.

Any ideas what's going on here?

UPDATE: Here is an image of the trace from module notifications in IIS.  Note that my module, FBAuth, is seeing AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST multiple times (I'd expect 2 - one for authenticate and one for postauthenticate, but I get 4).

[image: Events raised multiple times]

I'm starting to believe this has something to do with module/filter configuration because I've found a (Vista) box running the same code that doesn't fire these events repeatedly - it behaves as expected.  I'm working through trying to figure out what the difference could be...

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add the following code at the end of Application_BeginRequest:

```
if (Request.RawUrl.TrimEnd('/') == HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath.TrimEnd('/'))
    Server.Transfer(Request.RawUrl+"Default.aspx", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> DefaultHttpHandler is not supported,
>   so applications relying on sub-classes
>   of DefaultHttpHandler will not be able
>   to serve requests If your application
>   uses DefaultHttpHandler or handlers
>   that derive from DefaultHttpHandler,
>   it will not function correctly. In
>   Integrated mode, handlers derived from
>   DefaultHttpHandler will not be able to
>   pass the request back to IIS for
>   processing, and instead serve the
>   requested resource as a static file.
>   Integrated mode allows ASP.NET modules
>   to run for all requests without
>   requiring the use of
>   DefaultHttpHandler.
>  **Workaround**
>
> Change your application to use
>   modules to perform request processing
>   for all requests, instead of using
>   wildcard mapping to map ASP.NET to all
>   requests and then using
>   DefaultHttpHandler derived handlers to
>   pass the request back to IIS.
>   Hmmm, or this could be the issue.
>   ASP.NET modules in early request
>   processing stages will see requests
>   that previously may have been rejected
>   by IIS prior to entering ASP.NET,
>   which includes modules running in
>   BeginRequest seeing anonymous requests
>   for resources that require
>   authentication ASP.NET modules can run
>   in any pipeline stages that are
>   available to native IIS modules.
>   Because of this, requests that
>   previously may have been rejected in
>   the authentication stage (such as
>   anonymous requests for resources that
>   require authentication) or other
>   stages prior to entering ASP.NET may
>   run ASP.NET modules.  This behavior is
>   by design in order to enable ASP.NET
>   modules to extend IIS in all request
>   processing stages. 
> **Workaround**
>
> Change application code to avoid
>   any application-specific problems that
>   arise from seeing requests that may be
>   rejected later on during request
>   processing. This may involve changing
>   modules to subscribe to pipeline
>   events that are raised later during
>   request processing.
>   http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70/

Comment: Great link, although I don't believe I'm encountering any of those issues.  I'm working with a module, not a handler, and the event I'm monitoring is the authentication event.  Although it's possible this explains why I'm seeing it twice, it doesn't explain why the http info is lost (ex. form vars).